# create and handle conditions with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a parent function which should run 2 tests on a data set.
if any of these tests fail parent function should return fail. I want to run these 2 tests asynchronously with **asyncio** and as soon as one of the tests failed, parent function should return fail and cancel the other test. 
I'm new to *asyncio* and read some examples with the condition [here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/85359/asyncio.Condition) but couldn't figure out how to write asyncio with conditions.
so far I could handle it by throwing exceptions in any test that has been failed. 
here is my basic code:

```
async def test1(data):
    # run some test on data and return true on pass and throw exception on fail

async def test2(data):
    # run some test on data and return true on pass and throw exception on fail


ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [ioloop.create_task(test1(data)), ioloop.create_task(test2(data))]
finished, unfinished = ioloop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION))
```

but I don't think it's a proper way to handle conditions. 
so I want a basic example of how to create and handle conditions with *ayncio*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> as soon as one of the tests failed, parent function should return fail and cancel the other test.

[`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) does that automatically:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [loop.create_task(test1(data)), loop.create_task(test2(data))]
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
except FailException:  # use exception raised by the task that fails
    print('failed')
```

When any task executed in `asyncio.gather` raises an exception, all other tasks will be canceled using [`Task.cancel`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel), and the exception will be propagated to the awaiter of `gather`. You don't need a `Condition` at all, cancellation will automatically interrupt whatever blocking operation the tasks were waiting on.

Conditions are needed when a task that is otherwise idle (or many such tasks) needs to wait for an event that can happen in some other task. In that case it waits on a condition and is *notified* of it occurring. If the task is just going about its business, you can cancel it any time you like, or let functions like `asyncio.gather` or `asyncio.wait_for` do it for you.